# Will a security camera or tiny hidden camera lens cause a colored dot appear on an IR detector card? Why or why not?

Tags: sensors

Will a security camera or tiny hidden camera lens cause a colored dot appear on an IR detector card? Why or why not?

Comment: why would a lens create a dot? ... are you asking about a flaw in a lens?

Comment: I see why you are asking: https://www.google.com/search?q=Anti-Spy+Camera+Finder+infrared look for a review of the device.

Comment: A camera in and of itself does not emit infrared light and won't shot up with purely just an IR phosphorescent card. But that's not to say can't reflect a light source shining at it and produce an effect similar to how a cat's eye reflects light in the dark.

Comment: @DKNguyen cat's eye has a reflective layer behind the retina ... I do not know if the camera structure would respond the same way ... the lens would probably have a non-reflective coating

Comment: @jsotola I don't either which is why I did not actually say it would.

Answer (score 1):

> "Will a security camera or tiny hidden camera lens cause a colored dot appear on an IR detector card? Why or why not?"

Yes, infrared light is reflected off of the lens coating; giving the lens the appearance of a mirror, here are some examples:

- http://optishell.com/CineGuard.html

[image]

[image]

[image]

- US Patents [US6771349B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6771349B2/en) and [US20040094697A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20040094697A1/en).